# Aliases for Complex Type Property Names in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

My DBA calls his column names something different than how our code uses the table data (e.g. description vs product name). I'm wondering if I have a complex type in the Entity Framework, is it possible to give a property an alias?

Comment: I would say @Ladislav Mrnka has the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can name the property as you want and simply map the database field to that property. Name of properties are not dependent on names of related database columns.

Comment: How is that accomplished? The only fields I see in the Model Browser for the Complex Type's Property are Concurrency Mode, Default Value, Documentation, Getter, Name, Nullable, Setter, StoreGeneratedPattern and Type. I'm assuming that the Name needs to map to the column name in the table.

Comment: Mrnka is correct. Just change the Name to the Property Name you want. It does not have to be the column name. That is handled in the mapping...

Answer (score 3):

Are you using EntityFramework Code-First? When you mention Complex Type that is what I think of. If so it would help you get a better answer if you provided that information...

If that is the case here is a great article by ScottGu on [Custom Database Schema Mapping](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)

The code looks something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityName>().MapSingleType(t => new {
        columnId = t.Id,
        description = t.ProductName // If database column name is description and your entity property name is ProductName
        product_name = t.Description // If it's the other way around...
    }).ToTable("DatabaseTableName");
}
```

Comment: I'm not using code-first. I would use the option to automatically generate the complex type from the function import wizard, but the stored proc yields no columns due to the nature of the proc. Therefore, I am manually creating a complex type and adding properties that match the names of the columns in the result set. I'm not a fan of the result set column names as they don't exactly follow our business logic and so I would like to give them aliases that more closely resemble what the business calls them.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio there is a screen/panel call Mapping Details. By default its usually visible at the bottom tabs near error list, output and etc when you have the designer screen open “EF4”. In the designer view when you click on table the below panel will fill up with columns (from the database table) and Values/Properties (from your class). In Values/Properties you can change the name and type to whatever you want for your class. I do this regularly when the DBA starts creating rubbish column name(s) or starts using prefixes in some places and not in others.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Here example how to change a complex type if really need to, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2010/07/26/ef4-complex-type.aspx

Comment: I see the Mapping Details panel, but it only shows the mappings for Entities, not for Complex Types. The Complex Type I am working with shows in the Model Browser. When I select the Complex Type or it's property, the Mapping Details panel says, "Select an Entity or Association on the Entity Designer or Model Browser to edit its mappings".

Comment: If just want to change the entity name, properties than model details panel is the place. I don't understand why you'd want to create complex type EF4 another than addressline. Otherwise its better to write an sp and use the new entity type EF4 creates or rename it.